# Is there any way to make the template get updated when the model is updated?

Tags: freemarker

I am using FreeMarker to generate an HTML.
However, I would like the template to get updated if I update the model.

Is it possible to achieve this kind of request ?

It just doesn't make sense to call to template.process(..) every time the model changes.

Thanks !

Comment: How could it work otherwise? How's that HTML consumed?

Comment: I have created a Java FX app which pulls some information from some web services and shows it to the user. I thought it would be great if the user see it as an HTML. so I generate the HTML with FreeMarker.

Comment: Why's calling `template.process` a problem? Do you only want to change the existing HTML where a changed data is shown or something like that?

Comment: I don't see the inconvenience of refreshing the whole HTML when the model changes, if the HTML is huge and the user experience is compromised perhaps you could divide the DOM in modules, periodically ask the model for updates and refresh those parts of the DOM that are affected, javascript would work great for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess it's not possible to have the html changed whenever the model is updated. Thanks ! :)